# geckofx in separated thread - c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm using GeckoFx 22.

Code in button (that below) working fine only once. When press the button a second time (in a single run of the program), I get an error NullReferenceException (in a Navigate method). Is it possible to fix it?

```
class SomeClass
{
    private GeckoWebBrowser _webBrowser;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        if ( !Xpcom.IsInitialized )
        {
            Xpcom.Initialize( Application.StartupPath + "\\xulrunner" );
        }
        this._webBrowser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        this._webBrowser.Navigate( "http://google.com/" ); // here exception
    }
}

...
private void Work()
{
    try
    {
        var sc = new SomeClass();
        sc.Navigate();
        MessageBox.Show( "Done" );
    }
    catch ( Exception exception )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( exception.Message );
    }
}

private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Thread thread = new Thread( Work );
    thread.SetApartmentState( ApartmentState.STA );
    thread.Start();
}
...
```

Comment: On what line do you get the exception?

Comment: @Stormenet, in a navigate method.

Comment: You're manipulating a UI element from a non-UI thread, by the looks of it, so even if you're not getting a NRE, you'll be having other problems instead.  You should only be manipulating UI elements from the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy, how correctly to do this in a separate class, and that the application does not freeze during operation? P.S. Btw, this code works fine with the standard WebBrowser (IE).

Comment: @dedoki Well, the `Navigate` method shouldn't be blocking; it should be asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy, i know, but the code above is only an example. I need to load the page, get attributes values ​​of some elements, etc.

Comment: @dedoki And you do that through asynchrony, not additional threads.  You start an asynchronous operation, when it finishes (it appears that an event fires to signal completion) you do the next thing, and so on, in that manor.